# @synthesize vs. use of self

Tags: ios, properties

I am new to iOS, and have been learning from tutorials and from my professor.
In the `.h` file we have:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myResponse;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myInput;

@end
```

In the `.m` file we have:

```
@sysnthesize myResponse
@synthesize myInput
```

My question is this: What is the difference, in the `.m` file, between added the `@synthesize` and then using the properties like `[myInput <do something here>]` versus eliminating the `@synthesize` and using `[self.myInput <do something here>]`. I am running on Xcode 5, so I do understand that I have auto-synthesize available, but is there a more subtle difference between the two?

My professor used the `@synthesize` and the tutorial I was following was just using the `self.propertyName`, hence I am curious.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are just started to learn, best to read Apple documentation for most basic questions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html

Comment: and don't use @synthesize anymore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You no longer have to explicitly use `@synthesize` for properties. If your professor was using it, it was just to be explicit and demonstrate what's happening under the hood.

If your property is defined in the .h file, accessors, mutators and instance variables are automatically generated. If you explicitly `@synthesize` those properties, they are accessible via whatever ivar name is provided after the directive. If `@synthesize` is not used, the automatically generated ivars are available through `_somePropertyName`.

In your example, with the `@synthesize`, the `myResponse` UILabel is accessible through the instance variable `myResponse`. Without the `@synthesize`, it is available through `_myResponse`. In both cases, it is available through `self.myResponse`. It's best practice to use the instance variables in any lifecycle methods, accessors, or mutators (`-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear`, `-setMyResponse:`, etc) and to use `self.propertyName` in all other methods to clearly distinguish the properties of a class from the instance variables.