# Which is best:calling a property by @synthesize or by using self keyword

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, self, synthesize

Posting an ObjectiveC beginner level question. 
When I used properties to declare objects I see that we can access a particular property by 2 methods.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *str;
```

1. Use `@synthesize propertyname`
   eg:
   `@synthesize str;`
2. By using keyword `self`
   eg: `self.str;`

So what is the difference between these 2 methods and which is more suitable. Thanks for your time

Comment: Your two options do two completely different things.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355705/synthesize-vs-use-of-self

Comment: In my example I need to give a particular string to my variable str.So which method is most suitable and please be specific.Thankyou

Comment: Seems you need to add _str too to the list!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@synthesize` can not be used to access the property. It is a compiler directive. When you declare a property using using `@property`, the accessor methods (getter and setter) are automatically generated by the compiler. In the older versions, you had to explicitly use `@synthezie` to let the compiler know that it has to generate the accessor methods. With the newer versions, it is not required. The compiler automatically generates the accessor methods.

If you have declared the property as

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *str;
```

And if don't use @synthesize, then the ivar will be _str and the getter will be

```
-(NSString)str
```

and the setter will be

```
-(void)setStr:(NSString *)newStr
```

If you have mentioned the @synthesize specifically as

```
@synthesize str = _myStr
```

Then the ivar will be `_mystr` instead of `_str`.

So inorder to access the property str, you have to use `self.str` or `[self str]`